# Extending native HTML element in Angular 6

Tags: angular6, web-component, custom-element

I have recently created a native web component which is working well in all browsers. I moved this web component into an Angular 6 application and all works as expected. I then tried to extend a native HTML element which again worked perfectly except when I brought it into my Angular 6 application.

Using the examples from Mozilla I will try and illustrate my issue. Using the following trying to extend a native 'p' element:

```js
// Create a class for the element
class WordCount extends HTMLParagraphElement {
  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super();

    // count words in element's parent element
    var wcParent = this.parentNode;

    function countWords(node){
      var text = node.innerText || node.textContent
      return text.split(/\s+/g).length;
    }

    var count = 'Words: ' + countWords(wcParent);

    // Create a shadow root
    var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

    // Create text node and add word count to it
    var text = document.createElement('span');
    text.textContent = count;

    // Append it to the shadow root
    shadow.appendChild(text);


    // Update count when element content changes
    setInterval(function() {
      var count = 'Words: ' + countWords(wcParent);
      text.textContent = count;
    }, 200)

  }
}

// Define the new element
customElements.define('word-count', WordCount, { extends: 'p' });
```

```html
<p is="word-count">This is some text</p>
```

By taking that same code and putting it into an Angular 6 application, the component never runs. I put console log statements in the constructor and connectedCallback methods and they never trigger. If I remove the {extends: 'p'} object and change the extends HTMLParagraphElement and make it an extend HTMLElement to be an autonomous custom element everything works beautifully. Am I doing something wrong or does Angular 6 not support the customized built-in element extension?

Comment: I don't know how Angular is supposed to "support" customized built-ins - to any framework/library/third-party code that should just be an HTML element which should ofc work. It not working to me rather is an indicator of your transpilation/bundling setup not working properly. Are you using Typescript to compile your webcomponent along with Angular code?

Comment: My understanding is that custom elements are supported at the browser level (in certain browsers) and I have gotten this exact code to work by just importing it into a plain HTML file. I was under the assumption that moving this code to Angular would continue to work without the need or any sort of Transpiling or building. Again, with my example, if I create a custom element and do not try to extend an element, it works in Angular. The second I try using the {extends: 'p'} it stops working. Didn't think I would need to do anything specific to get it to work in Angular.

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz showcasing the issue?

Comment: Sure - here is an example of it working outside of angular https://stackblitz.com/edit/customized-built-in-element

Here is the same component in Angular not working (I also added CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA)  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-52fs9p

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped you as I'm also curious as of how to get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

I assume the reason is the way that Angular creates those customized built-in elements when parsing component templates - it probably does not know how to properly do that. Odds are it considers `is` a regular attribute which is fine to add *after* creation of the element (which it isn't).

First creating the element and then adding the `is`-attribute will unfortunately **not** upgrade the element.

See below example: `div#d` has a non-working example of that customized `input`.

```js
customElements.define('my-input', class extends HTMLInputElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.value = this.parentNode.id
    this.parentNode.classList.add('connected')
  }
}, {
  extends: 'input'
})

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  b.innerHTML = `<input type="text" is="my-input">`

  let el = document.createElement('input', {
    is: 'my-input'
  })
  el.type = 'text'
  c.appendChild(el)

  // will not work:
  let el2 = document.createElement('input')
  el2.setAttribute('is', 'my-input')
  el2.type = 'text'
  d.appendChild(el2)
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 3px dotted #999;
  padding: 10px;
}

div::before {
  content: "#"attr(id)" ";
}

.connected {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"><input type="text" is="my-input"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>
```

So to get it to work with Angular, hook into the lifecycle of your Angular component (e.g. `onInit()` callback) and pick a working way to create your element there.

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate all the help @connexo and understanding my rambling. This really helped and I would upvote 10 times if I could.

Comment: same problem with Svelte.