# Extended custom elements not working in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular

I can't get Angular (2+, not AngularJS) to play nice with my extended custom element, which is defined like so:

```
  class FancyButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerText = `I'm a fancy-button!`;
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'tomato';
    }
  }

  customElements.define("fancy-button", FancyButton, {
    extends: "button"
  });
```

And used like so:

```
<button is="fancy-button">Fancy button here</button>
```

The definition is fully compliant to web standards according to this Google Developer resource:
[https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#extend](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dginkc)

It's working fine in a vanilla web setup and in React, but Angular ignores it and shows a standard button, apparently ignoring the *is="fancy-button"* attribute.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dginkc) showing this in action.
One fancy-button is outside the Angular scope (index.html) and is working fine.
The other button is inside the Angular scope (app.component.html) and is NOT working.

Why oh why?

Comment: I wouldn't even go that way... we have directives to use just for cases like this :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lqz3xt?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I see. I'm doing this to be framework agnostic and I think the "is="fancy-button" approach is very nice for that. Works perfectly in React without any React-specific code.

Comment: I'm not using the <script> tag in a template. It's in the index.html file. However, I get your point and thanks for your reply.
This question is about the same issue if you're interested:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604958/extending-native-html-element-in-angular-6

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of **Custom Elements**:

1. **Autonomous Custom Elements**, which are classes that `extend HTMLElement`
2. **Customized Built-in Elements**, which are classes that extend a
   specific type of element, such as `extend HTMLButtonElement`.

Customized Built-in Elements are not supported in Angular (more details
on this below).  They are also still not supported in Safari (as of
Sep 2020: https://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20elements
).

Your example is a Customized Built-in Element.  The workaround that has
worked for me is to rewrite any Customized Built-in Element as an Autonomous
Custom Element wrapped around a Built-in Element.  This gives me the
encapsulation I want, it gives me a way to customize the built-in, and it works with Angular and Safari.

For your example above, the translation is:

```
class FancyButtonToo extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    const buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
    this.appendChild(buttonElement);
    buttonElement.innerText = "Fancy button #2 here!";
    buttonElement.style.backgroundColor = 'tomato';
  }
}

customElements.define("fancy-button-too", FancyButtonToo);
```

(The project also needed `schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMAS]` added
to `app.module.ts`).  Full code here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lpy1q6?file=src%2Findex.html),
and it renders like this (original "fancy-button" left in for comparison):

[image]

#### Additional Info

Q: Are we certain Angular cannot support Customized Built-in Elements (as
opposed to, say, there being some obscure configuration we are not aware of)?

A: We are certain: The spec document at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-autonomous-example
goes into deep detail on the differences between Autonomous Custom Elements
and Customized Built-in Elements.  One important difference is in
programmatic construction of elements:

```
// Built-in Elements and Autonomous Custom Elements are created like this:
el = createElement(name);
// examples
el = createElement("button"); // normal built-in button
el = createElement("fancy-text"); // a custom element

// Customized Built-in Elements are created like this:
el = createElement(built-in-name, { is: custom-built-in-name });
// example
el = createElement("button", { is: "fancy-button" });
```

The relevant Angular template-rendering code is found at
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.ts
and as of the current version of Angular, you will find:

```
class DefaultDomRenderer2 implements Renderer2 {
  /* ... */
  createElement(name: string, namespace?: string): any {
    if (namespace) {
      return document.createElementNS(NAMESPACE_URIS[namespace] || namespace, name);
    }
    return document.createElement(name);
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

The Angular renderer currently does not have the extra code
needed to pass in the 2nd argument to `createElement()`; it cannot
create Custom Built-in Elements.

Comment: have you thought about sending a contribution to the angular repository with this improvement?

Comment: your suggestion

    create(name: string, namespaceOrOptions?: string | ElementCreationOptions) {
  if (namespaceOrOptions && typeof namespaceOrOptions === 'string') {
    return document.createElementNS(NAMESPACE_URIS[namespaceOrOptions] || namespaceOrOptions, name);
  }
  if (namespaceOrOptions && namespaceOrOptions.hasOwnProperty('is')) {
    return document.createElement(name, namespaceOrOptions as ElementCreationOptions);
  }
  return document.createElement(name)
}

would it be something like that @John C?

Comment: angular is doing big mistake. with increasing popularity of custom elements, they should simply add this tiny polyfill (https://github.com/ungap/custom-elements) and support `is` prop. which will increase just ~2kb in its already huge bundle.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class DefaultDomRenderer2 implements Renderer2 {
  // ...
  create(name: string, namespaceOrOptions?: string | ElementCreationOptions) {
    if (namespaceOrOptions && typeof namespaceOrOptions === 'string') {
      // In cases where Ivy (not ViewEngine) is giving us the actual namespace, the look up by key
      // will result in undefined, so we just return the namespace here.
      return document.createElementNS(NAMESPACE_URIS[namespaceOrOptions] || namespaceOrOptions, name);
    }
    if (namespaceOrOptions && namespaceOrOptions.hasOwnProperty('is')) {
      return document.createElement(name, namespaceOrOptions as ElementCreationOptions);
    }
    return document.createElement(name)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the polyfill javascript file with your project and then it should work:
https://github.com/ungap/custom-elements